# Is it possible to call the mobile version of an website inside an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, mobile

So, basically I have an image of a phone with transparent screen in which i placed an iframe. Now to let it seem like the website is in the phone I want the website to be display as mobile version.
Now its like i would just squash the window.

Comment: Just make the iframe the size of a phone

Comment: the content of the iframe should be like on a phone. I already resized it so it would fit but the website itself, the content, is just smushed together. It doesnt look good

Comment: That's a problem with the website. It should rely on screen size, not anything else to determine whether to show the "mobile" version. The modern approach is to just use [media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7354648/227299).

Comment: If it was a responsive website it should have respond to mobile width. This website probably redirected you to a different url for mobile using some auto-detecting method.

Comment: Is there a mobile version of the site, such as m.facebook.com? Do you control the website you are putting in an iframe?

Comment: No, I dont really control this site. Its probably just a bad site tbh.

Comment: Does it offer a version of the site that is meant to be embedded in an iframe? It's a security risk for most sites to let itself be put in an iframe without making sure it's not subject to [clickjacking](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Clickjacking)